# Combo Box in Ms Access does not dispaly values

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have a comobo box in ms-access whose record source is a query:
 **select WeightUOM from Ctr where WeightUOM="lbs" or WeightUOM="sh t".**
When I run my form the combo box does not display any value.Although running the query independently fetches correct result.

Thanks!!

Comment: You mean the combobox dropdown list does not show any rows?

Comment: I suppose you mean the [Row Source] property of the ComboBox? Ensure that the [Row Source Type] property set to "Table/Query". Ensure that the [Column Width] property is not set to 0.

Comment: @CPerkins You just saved my life after two days of banging my head against a working SQL statement that wasn't displaying, column width was set to 0